# What's the best way to use `test::TestDescAndFn` without using libtest?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a custom test-runner for a custom target, that doesn't have libtest available. However I would like to use the `TestDescAndFn` struct, which is defined in libtest, in my own test-runner. `TestDescAndFn` provides information about the tests such as if it should panic or not, the name of the test and others, so having this information would be really useful compared to just using `#[test_case]`.

Since the `#[test]` annotation is resolved at compile-time and simply generates a test harness that calls a (custom) test-runner I can define with `#![test_runner(my_test_runner)]`, I don't think I really need libtest aside from `TestDescAndFn`and the enums it contains. Is there any "good" way to use the definitions from libtest for `TestDescAndFn`, `TestDesc` etc., without actually building libtest?

Answer (score 1):

The [`test`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/test/index.html) crate provides `TestDescAndFn` and is provided by the compiler.  So, your custom framework crate might do something like this:

```
#![feature(test)]
// provided by compiler, no need to specify dependency in Cargo.toml
extern crate test;

use ::test::TestDescAndFn;

pub fn run_tests(tests: &[&TestDescAndFn]) {
    // ...
}
```

and then your crate under test would do this:

```
#![feature(custom_test_frameworks)]
#![test_runner(::my_framework::run_tests)]

// crate with #[test] as normal
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using test? I'd like to avoid using `test` since test uses `std` and `panic_abort` in the case of my target. This is problematic since I already use a custom `panic_handler`. Basically what I would like to do is use `test::TestDescAndFn`, but without raking in `std`and `panic_abort` into my dependencies.

Comment: @jschw Perhaps you should look into the [`utest`](https://github.com/japaric/utest) crate?

Comment: Or change your `#[panic_handler]` to `#[cfg_attr(not(test), panic_handler]` and be content with rest harnesses that bring in their own.